# VPN connectivity issues after disconnecting from VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, udp, voice

So I am using HotSpot shield VPN and everything works fine except checking my local news station.

I can play games and use voice chat ( discord / bnet chat)  with the VPN on.

However... when I turn off VPN  I lose voice coms ( UDP ) and can not connect to bnet launcher app or other gaming services.  What is weird is I can view webpages and my news network with the VPN off.

What is going on here... I am completely lost as I don't even know where to start.  Some network adapter issue?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own problem... a while back I changed the IPv4 security settings to high on my router / gateway.  Changed it back to low.  I assume because the ports where blocked, this was the problem I was having ... the VPN by passed these?

Answer (score 0):

VPNs work by routing your traffic through an encrypted network, and exiting that network in another physical place. This place may be very far away from the place you actually are, which interferes with geo-locality features designed into the internet.

For instance, many US news organizations are run by large conglomerates, who handle their websites. They have a pool of DNS names like "post.com" or "journal.com", so in one region the local post resolves to one organization, and in another region, it resolves to another. Or is blackholed, in the case of region-locked content (which is ironically why many people use a VPN at all).

As for UDP, thats a problem with the protocol itself. TCP can just establish a new connection on the new network, but for UDP, an application must knowingly restart the stream. It depends entirely on the application in question how smooth the resumption process will be.